# Block access by Geo location

Tags: security, firewall, geoip

I'm wondering if it's possible to block access based on location, as many hackers and ransomware attacks  in recent years came from Russia or Belarus etc.

I dont want my vps accessed by those countries. I'm aware that there's ways around this, such as VPN, but it will reduce the attacks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 block countries access to my server (ssh & nginx)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072001/ubuntu-18-04-block-countries-access-to-my-server-ssh-nginx)

Comment: tnX thou im not looking for nginx etc not web based otherwise i can use even cloudflare etc for that matter

Answer (score 0):

To block access from a specific country or region, you should use the blacklist for IP ranges or use the whitelist for allowed locations, it's not easy to get IP lists.