# Block ips from certain country and security

Tags: server, security, firewall, nginx, ufw

I have an Ubuntu Server 22.04 with Nginx installed along with a laravel application.

When I view the access logs I can see a lot of attempts from a certain country to exploit my server and application. For example:

```
109.237.97.141 - - [14/Mar/2023:05:06:49 +0000] "POST /_ignition/execute-solution HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
198.235.24.171 - - [14/Mar/2023:05:47:28 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xCA\x01\x00\x00\xC6\x03\x03\xD8\xE1v\xDDn/\x17S\xD0:\x83J\xD0 n\xDFk\x975$S\x09\xCD\x87\xA5\xC5\xB3b\xD4<\x9AC\x00\x00h\xCC\x14\xCC\x13\xC0/\xC0+\xC00\xC0,\xC0\x11\xC0\x07\xC0'\xC0#\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"
5.188.210.227 - - [14/Mar/2023:09:20:53 +0000] "\x05\x01\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
5.188.210.227 - - [14/Mar/2023:09:21:57 +0000] "\x04\x01\x00P\x05\xBC\xD2\xE3\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
52.27.236.62 - - [14/Mar/2023:09:21:58 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
52.27.236.62 - - [14/Mar/2023:09:21:58 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03M," 400 166 "-" "-"
52.27.236.62 - - [14/Mar/2023:09:21:59 +0000] "POST /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36"
```

Currently UFW status is set to the following with letsencrypt ssl installed :

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

What is the best approach to block ips from this country. Would you implement it at nginx level or   UFW level?

Please can someone provide details of how to implement ubuntu firewall security to mitigate or manage such attacks. Many thanks

Comment: "Would you implement it at nginx level or UFW level?" is asking for opinions.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072001/ubuntu-18-04-block-countries-access-to-my-server-ssh-nginx also already covers what you ask. for nginx you need the geo module compiled in nginx so that might not be an option anyways leaving only  UFW.

Comment: @Rinzwind merely asking for advice and the link you posted doesn't provide much detail. How would i implement with UFW?