# Are UFW IP groups possible?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I have a giant list of IP addresses I need to manage incoming access for. They are also constantly changing.

Is there a way to create a group of IP addresses/ranges for a firewall rule?

That way, when a rule needs to change/add/delete for that group, I can just change the rule, and not have to type in the whole group?

Something analog to:

```
ufw allow in from IP_GROUP_1 port 443
```

If not, any tips you have on this are valued.

Thanks!

EDIT: answers for IPTABLES and not UFW are fine.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do what you want with iptables, but I don't know about ufw. I didn't write an answer because you specifically mention UFW. For iptables, probably using ipset would be the easiest.

Comment: I would be totally fine with an answer for iptables.

Comment: you mean like this: `sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.1.16/28 to 192.168.1.48 port 80`  ?

Comment: Have a look at the ipset answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868334/block-china-with-iptables/). I do it a little different and not via a cron job.

Comment: Rinzwind that's not really what I'm looking for because we have many subnets and random IPs. not just ranges.